# MySql Select if the previous Select is Empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.
**Song table** that contains all the songs that I can listen.
**Archive table** where I put the songs played with date and time.

What I would do is ask the database to give me a song:

1) Do not ever played (not present in the table Archive)

.... if not possible

2) Be present in the Archives but has been played at least 24 hours before

.... if not possible

3) Whether this in Archive but the artist of the song has been played at least 3 hours before

4) Finally, if there is no result I would like the database returns a random song from the **Song table**

```
(
        SELECT song.* 
        FROM 
        song AS song
        LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT song_artist 
                  FROM archive 
                  WHERE customer_id=50
                  AND genre=32
                  AND channel=44
                  AND archive_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)

                ) 
            AS archive_a
            ON song.song_artist = archive_a.song_artist

            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT song_id 
                  FROM archive 
                  WHERE customer_id=50 
                  AND genre=32
                  AND channel=44
              AND archive_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)

                )
        AS archive_b
            ON song.song_id = archive_b.song_id

            LEFT JOIN
                ( SELECT a.song_id FROM song a
                LEFT JOIN archive b
                ON a.song_id = b.song_id

                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT null 
                    FROM archive c
                    WHERE customer_id=50
                    AND genre=32
                    AND channel=44
                    AND c.song_id = a.song_id

                )

                )
            AS song_c
            ON song.song_id = song_c.song_id

        WHERE FIND_IN_SET('32', genre) <> 0
        AND archive_a.song_artist Is Null
        AND archive_b.song_id Is Null
        AND song_c.song_id Is Null
        GROUP BY song_artist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
        )

        UNION

        (
        SELECT song.* 
        FROM 
            song AS song

        WHERE FIND_IN_SET('32', genre) <> 0
        GROUP BY song_artist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
    )
```

I have tried in this world but not working

Answer (score 0):

remove archive conditions from where and use it as join conditions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you Logan for your advice and sorry for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, even though you could write this as a single query using unions, I would not do that. The reason is simple: you want to select a random song (record) matching any of the above criteria.

I would rather issue a query trying to get a song that's been never played before, process the results in your application and if no record is returned, then proceeed with the next query.

If you insist on combining the 4 criteria in a single query, even then I would write 4 queries and combine them with union into a single one. Additionally, I would not use the order by rand() because it does not scale well. I would execute queries to determine the number (count) of records matching each criteria, determine a random number between 0 and count-1, and use limit clause to select a random record. If a count returns with 0, then you can omit that query from the union.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, your answer was useful!